# Kivy buildozer Pil/Pillow eror

Tags: python, kivy, python-imaging-library, buildozer

Has anyone been able to get pil/pillow to work on Buildozer recently?
It used to work on the old python-for-android but not anyone.

*I'm currently using Kivy complete VM 0.5, api 27, sdk 23, ndk 17c.*

I have been trying it for almost 5 months now and still no luck, 
I tried adding pil, Pillow to the buildozer requirements but nothing works... I even tried downloading it from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil

Any help will be appreciated.

pillow error:

```
ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "jsimd_h2v1_downsample" referenced by /PIL/_imaging.so"
```

Pil errors:

```
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed

 _imaging C is 64 bit instead of 32 bit
```

**EDIT:**
with p4a.branch= master

```
[INFO]:    Prebuilding Pillow for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Pillow has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for Pillow[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    Applying patch patches/fix-docstring.patch
[INFO]:    -> running patch -t -d /home/kivy/Desktop...(and 259 more)
[INFO]:    Applying patch patches/fix-setup.patch
[INFO]:    -> running patch -t -d /home/kivy/Desktop...(and 255 more)
[INFO]:    -> running touch /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/...(and 110 more)
[INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    Applying patch sdl2_jnienv_getter.patch
[INFO]:    -> running patch -t -d /home/kivy/Desktop...(and 264 more)
      [INFO]:    -> running touch /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/...(and 117 more)    
[INFO]:    Prebuilding android for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    android has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/android-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    # Building recipes
[INFO]:    Building harfbuzz for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/harfbuzz/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/harfbuzz
[INFO]:    -> running configure --without-icu --host...(and 161 more)
           working:  Documentation:  no                      [INFO]:    -> running make -j5
           working: [INFO]:    -> running cp -L src/.libs/libharfbuzz.a ...(and 85 more)
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Building hostpython2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2/native-build
[INFO]:    -> running configure
           working: creating Ma[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running cp Modules/Setup.dist /home/ki...(and 127 more)
[INFO]:    -> running make -j 1 -C /home/kivy/Deskto...(and 104 more)
           working: copyin[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Building jpeg for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1081, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1075, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 577, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 151, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 200, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 562, in build_recipes
  File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/recipes/jpeg/__init__.py", line 37, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.cmake, '-G', 'Unix Makefiles',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 3349, in __getattr__
    return self.__env[name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 3226, in __getitem__
    raise CommandNotFound(k)
sh.CommandNotFound: cmake
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=PicApp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=hostpython2,python2,kivy==master,plyer,android,Pillow --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
```

Comment: I thought pil is currently working. In your build log, do you see p4a attempting to install it from a recipe? A possible reason for your problem is that it is not doing so, and instead compiling it wrong after getting it from pypi.

Comment: With python-for-android master, you would want to write "Pillow" in the requirements, the case might be important.

Comment: @inclement It compiles succesfully with p4a.branch = stable but still causes the app to crash... but with master it doesn't compile at all. And yes I see it installing. please check out my edit for the build log. Thanks!

Comment: It *doesn't* compile successfully with p4a.branch = stable, that's your whole problem. The '_imaging C is 64 bit instead of 32 bit' error is probably because it's packaged a version compiled for your local PC, not for Android. The build error you posted seems to indicate that you should install cmake.

Comment: @inclement thanks for your help! After installing cmake, I get `STDOUT:
CMake Error: No source or binary directory provided`

Comment: cmake 3.13.2 works

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error before, I uninstalled pillow then reinstalled it simply worked for me

if you use python3 replace python with python3 below

to uninstall

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pillow
```

to install

```
sudo python -m pip install pillow
```